# Using the Google directions for an animated drive (Google Maps API V3)

Tags: google-maps-api-3

does anyone know how to do it in API V3, or where to find info about this option

http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=en&tl=pl&u=http%3A%2F%2Feconym.org.uk%2Fgmap%2F&anno=2

do help me pls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Larry at geocodezip has re-worked many of the econym examples.

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a solution before knowing of this post. I think is short and concise, so  I hope it helps anyone that see this in the future.

**STEP 1:** Pass the response parameter from `directionsService.route()` to a function that I call it  `driveSim(response)`:

```
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
       directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
       driveSim(response);
    };
});
```

**STEP 2:** Create the marker with its initial position equals to that of the response initial position, then iterate over all values in the `path` array of objects and thats it. It just animates it at a fixed spped that is not correlated to any specific speed. If you wish to do that just use `console.log(path);` to explore all data in `var path` object and you will see it is quite easy to figure out the delay required for a given speed.

```
function driveSim (response){
    var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
    var maxIter=path.length;

    taxiCab=new google.maps.Marker({
       position: path[0],
       map: map, 
    });

    var delay = 20, count = 0;
    function delayed () {
      count += 1;
      taxiCab.setPosition({lat:path[count].lat(),lng:path[count].lng()});
      if (count < maxIter-1) {
        setTimeout(delayed, delay);
      }
    }
    delayed();
}
```

AND, that's it.